# Script section in angular controller function was not hit also the values are not assigned

Tags: angularjs

In my application I want to load my external html file when I click the navigation links.
[index.html]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="defaultApp">
<head>
</head>
<body ng-controller="defaultCtrl">

    <!--dynamic content load from external html files-->

</body>
</html>
```

In my `app.js` file, I have defined the default routing values with controller function for my external file navigation.
[app.js]

```
            var mainApp = angular.module('defaultApp', ['ngRoute']);

            mainApp.controller("defaultCtrl", ['$scope', '$rootScope','$compile', function ($scope, $rootScope,$compile) {   
                $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (event) {        
                    $compile($('#sync').contents())($scope);        
                });
            }])
             mainApp.config(['$routeProvider',
                     function($routeProvider) {
                        $routeProvider.
                           when('/addStudent', {
                              templateUrl: 'sample/addStudent.htm',
                              controller: 'AddStudentController'
                           }).
                           otherwise({
                              redirectTo: '/addStudent'
                           });
                     }]);


                  mainApp.controller("AddStudentController", ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {

                      $rootScope.url = 'sample/addStudent.htm'

                  }])
```

In my all external html files have our controls declaration statements and have script section to assign the values in controller function.
[addStudent.html]

```
             <div id="sync">
            <div id='sample'>
            <p>This is a sample</p>
            </div>

            <script>    
               mainApp.controller('AddStudentController', function($scope) {
                        $scope.message = "This page will be used to display add student form";
                     }); 
            </script>
            </div>
```

if i run my application, the external sample content loaded into my layout page. But the script section in angular controller function was not hit also the values are not assigned. So the output will render without any model values. (like output rendered with default model values)
                So could please suggest the solution is more needful.

Comment: You shouldnt define the same controller twice

Comment: how can i load  the script section in angular controller (external file)function in layout page

Comment: you dont anyways need to do that...give the script data directly inside you controller

Comment: I need to do it in extenal file.need to maintain externalfile.Can you please suggest me ,how to  load  the external script section in layoutpage

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your code where you have defined your controller

```
app.controller("defaultCtrl",..
```

change it to

```
 mainApp.controller("defaultCtrl",..
```

Comment: I have  defined mainApp.controller(".....Then also,i can' load the script section(defined in externalfile)in layoutpage